# Is consecutive partial differentiation commutative?

Tags: calculus, partial-derivative

Are the following 2 operations guaranteed to give the same result?

$\frac{\partial}{\partial x}(\frac{\partial}{\partial y}(f(x, y)))$

$\frac{\partial}{\partial y}(\frac{\partial}{\partial x}(f(x, y)))$

Comment: Not if $f$ is discontinuous or if $f_{xy} $ and $f_{yx}$ are not continuous.

Comment: Assuming $f$ is defined on $\mathbb{R}^2$ and $f{\in}{C}^2(\mathbb{R}^2)$, yes. It's a consequence of Schwarz's theorem.